# Excel Doesn't Complete Macro after Opening Another Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get VBA to fire the commands

```
sImportFilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:= _
"Excel Files (*.xls), *.xls", Title:="Choose The Source File")
Application.Workbooks.Open (sImportFilePath)
sImportFileName = FunctionGetFileName(sImportFilePath)
```

And they work when I step through the function, but when I use the hotkey **Ctrl+Shift+F** or any other hotkey, the `Application.Workbooks.Open` command works but it navigates the the new Excel document, then doesn't do anything.  However, when I open "Macros" in the developer tab, select my macro, and click "Run" everything is runs fine.

Comment: You say it doesn't "do anything"  - what are you expecting to see?  Presumably there's more code following your posted sample.  What is FunctionGetFileName ?

Comment: The expected result would be execution of the next line, FunctionGetFileName, and continued execution through the document. FunctionGetFileName is a function I wrote elsewhere in the program which finds the FileName from the FilePath, but there's more code after that which also doesn't execute.  From further experimentation, however, I narrowed down the problem and revised the question accordingly.

Comment: What version of Excel?  Works for me in 2007 with Ctrl+Shift+F.

Comment: I'm using 2007 as well. I don't know why this shouldn't work.  Might it have something to do with using global variables?

Comment: Do you have any kind of error handling or "on error resume next" ?  If yes then comment that out and see what happens.  Does the workbook being opened have any auto_open macro ?

Comment: I had tried commenting out "on error resume next," but it didn't help.  The workbook shouldn't have any auto_open macro.

Comment: Contact me via email (should be in my profile) if you want to continue this.

Comment: Did you find out a solution to this?

Comment: @ebbflowgo It is 4 months later, but I found a solution to this problem (at least one that works for me)

Comment: @psubee2003 care to share it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I actually ran into this exact problem myself and finally found a solution to my problem.

It is the <kbd>Shift</kbd> button in the keyboard shortcut you are using to call your code.

Apparently there a feature in Excel specifically designed to prevent code from running when a workbook is opened and the **Shift** key is pressed, but unfortunately this also impacts opening workbooks with the `Workbook.Open` method via VBA.  This was mentioned in [KB Article 555263](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555263), applying to Excel 2000 & 2003, but I encountered the same problem in Excel 2010, so I imagine it is also impacting 2007 as well.

This occurs specifically when you try to open a workbook via code very early in the program.  If the `Workbook.Open` call is reached in code before you have had sufficient time to actually let go of the **Shift** button, Excel is interpreting that as an attempt to block code from running and aborts the process.  And there are no error messages or anything that I have found.  It just stops abruptly.

The workaround/fix is to force the code to wait for the Shift key to be released before issuing the `Workbook.Open` command.

Per the article, just add this code to your macro and that should do it:

```
'Declare API
Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "User32" (ByVal vKey As Integer) As Integer
Const SHIFT_KEY = 16

Function ShiftPressed() As Boolean
'Returns True if shift key is pressed
    ShiftPressed = GetKeyState(SHIFT_KEY) < 0
End Function

Sub Demo()
    Do While ShiftPressed()
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\MyPath\MyFile.xlsx"
End Sub
```

(NOTE: This code is for 32-bit versions of Excel.  64-bit versions will need to use the `PtrSafe` attribute on the `Declare` statement).

If you don't want to add the extra code, then your only other options are to not use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Some Letter</kbd> to launch a macro, or to put the `Workbook.Open` command later in the macro (not right at the beginning) in order to give yourself time to release the Shift button after starting it.

Comment: @psubee2003, this one was driving me around the bend, thanks for the fix.

Answer (score 4):

Just adding a single call to "DoEvents" before calling Workbooks.Open will already do the trick.
So the folloiwng snippet will work:

```
DoEvents
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\MyPath\MyFile.xlsx"
```

Comment: This is the easiest solution

Comment: @GlenHong it depends on what the actual issue is. If it is a shift button press, then `DoEvents` isn't going to address that,  But if it is something else, then yes, this answer is very easy to implement

Comment: For what it's worth this solution worked perfectly for me and the Shift one didn't. The workbook I was opening was on a network location so that may have been part of the situation.

Answer (score 1):

Question did you have a line of code selecting multiple tabs anytime before this line of code? I have found that this is sort of like holding in the shift key the entire time they're selected. To resolve this I had the macro ungroup (single select) a tab and the macro began working then.

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround that did it for me is to assign the VBA to a shortcut key without a shift. I'm not a big fan of doing so because there are many more conflicts with dafault Excel shortcuts. But there's a few available as of Excel 2010 based on [this article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/keyboard-shortcuts-in-excel-2010-HP010342494.aspx): Ctrl+e, Ctrl+j, Ctrl+m, Ctrl+q.

Comment: Welcome to SO! How does this answer add any value? There's already [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19712974/923794) describing this exact problem in more detail with another workaround, too. If you do want to answer old questions, ensure you're providing additional value.

Answer (score 0):

Temporary solution found on an French forum: use the below **ForEachWinDoEvents**
before activating the workbook of your choice.

```
Sub Test()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set w1 = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    Set w2 = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    Set w3 = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ForEachWinDoEvents
    w2.Activate
End Sub

Sub ForEachWinDoEvents()
Dim win As Window
  For Each win In Application.Windows
    DoEvents
  Next win
End Sub
```