# VBA script doesn't seem to run all the way through on the first try

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code that I'm using in a workbook to open another workbook,  check for the presence of two sheets, then for each one that's present, copy some data from the second workbook into the first, and finally close the second workbook. When I first started using it, it worked without issue. The problem I have now is that it'll open the second workbook but the code just stops running at that point. If I then run the code again with the workbook open, it will run through the whole thing. It's a minor annoyance but I'd rather not have to go through it twice, and I'd also like to understand why it may be happening.

```
Option Explicit

Sub UFR_Data_Extractor()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer

    ChDrive "C:"
    ChDir "C:\Users\ME\OneDrive\Documents\_Program Development & Planning\Market Database\UFRs"

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Select workbook to grab data from
    Dim strFileToOpen As String: strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls,", Title:="Please choose source data")
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strFileToOpen)
    Debug.Print "Opening "; strFileToOpen

    'Get Workbook Name only
    Dim trgWorkbook As String: trgWorkbook = Right(strFileToOpen, Len(strFileToOpen) - InStrRev(strFileToOpen, "\"))
    Debug.Print "Workbook name: " & trgWorkbook

    'Test for presence of target sheets
    Dim B_PSI1Found As Boolean: B_PSI1Found = False
    Dim B_PSI2Found As Boolean: B_PSI2Found = False

    For i = 1 To wb.Worksheets.Count
        If Worksheets(i).Name = "B_PSI" Then
            B_PSI1Found = True
        ElseIf Worksheets(i).Name = "B_PSI2" Then
            B_PSI2Found = True
        End If
    Next i
    Debug.Print "B_PSIFound = " & B_PSI1Found
    Debug.Print "B_PSI2Found = " & B_PSI2Found

    Call DataCopy(trgWorkbook, "B_PSI")

    If B_PSI2Found = True Then
        Call DataCopy(trgWorkbook, "B_PSI2")
    End If

    Workbooks(trgWorkbook).Close
    strFileToOpen = vbNullString
    trgWorkbook = vbNullString

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Debug.Print "Process Complete!"

End Sub
```

Comment: A few things; in your for loop you might want to consider specifying the `workbook` in your `If` statements. Also unless your problem is caused by the unspecified workbook, everything else.looks functional in this `Sub`, What is `DataCopy`? I'm thinking something in there might be causing your issue.

Comment: I made that change. DataCopy is another sub that does the actual copying of data from one sheet to another. I was thinking that it WASN'T the issue since the script doesn't seem to run to the point where it calls DataCopy. I know this because it doesn't even  Debug.Print "Opening "; strFileToOpen line, so I assume it's not running anything else.

Comment: What happens when you step through (F8)  your code?

Comment: Interestingly, it ran through without issue when I stepped through.

Comment: i should also clarify, how are you executing your code? Keyboard shortcut? Command button? F5 in the IDE?

Comment: I just tested on Excel 365 with no issues, the only modifications I made were the default path (to a local path on my machine) and I commented out the calls to the `DataCopy` sub to prevent a `Compile Error`. I excecuted the code from the IDE along with assigning a call to the sub on a `commandbutton_click` event.
The only other thing I was thinking was Excel is trying to execute the entire code before your workbook has opened, as it worked as expected when you stepped through your code but my testing doesn't confirm that. 
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6959005) may assist?

Comment: Wow, that's exactly it! I had a it tied to a keyboard shortcut (Ctrl+Shift+D). I'm really not married to it so I'll just tie it to a button instead of the shortcut. Thanks for your help and persistence!!!